# Rendering JSON array in two different "columns" from axios

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, strapi

I'm very new when it comes to axios and react.

My goal is to have half of the array rendered in one column and the other half in the second column. So i can style each of the columns separately.

I have an array of JSON objects that I would like to render in to columns like
this:

### OmOss.js

```
const OmOss = () => {
  return (
    <ContentContainer>
      <Column>
        <Element></Element>
      </Column>
      <Column>
        <Element></Element>
      </Column>
    </ContentContainer>
  );
};
```

Here is my get request with axios that returns all of the objects in the array as a single component.
But I can't figure out how to seperate each of those objects and render them seperately.

### Element.js

```
export function Element() {
  const url = "http://localhost:1337/om-osses";
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setResult(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <ContentContainer>
        <div> Loading... </div>
      </ContentContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <TextContainer>
      {result.map((text) => (
        <div>
          <Title text={text.Title} fontSize="2.3rem"></Title>
          <p>{text.Content}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </TextContainer>
  );
}
```

This is what i've tried.

- I've tried to push to an array like so

```
let data= [];
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setResult(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    data.push(response.data);
  }, []);
```

And acessing it like this:

```
<Title text={array[0].title} fontSize="2.3rem"></Title>
```

But the array element was undefined despite the axios request coming through successfully.

Comment: You are already updating the `result` state with response. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "render them separately"?

Comment: @RameshReddy The problem is that I don't want the entire array to be displayed twice which result.map seems to do. But i want it styled so half of the array will be displayed on in one column and the other half in the other column. 

Or array[0] & array[1] in column 1 and array[2] & [3] in column 2

Comment: Do you always have two columns? Go through my answer

Comment: @RameshReddy No not necessarily, depending on screen size I remove one of those columns.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a CSS solution. Dividing the array doesn't make any sense. What you need is a two-column layout using flex or grid.

Comment: I couldn't find any good solutions on how to handle that type of CSS layout.
where you have 2 columns with a length of X and having them be responsive

Answer (score 0):

You have problem here.

```
**let data= []**;
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setResult(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    **data.push(response.data)**; // Response is undefined at this moment
  }, []);
```

First of all, you declared data as a local variable and it would be erased to [] whenever the component is rendered again.

Second, you pushed data when there is no response.

To do what you want, you must declare data as state and use setter to use it.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      let newData = data;
      newData.push(response.data);
      setData(newData);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);
```

I am not sure what you reall want, but you can try in this way.

Comment: How would I go about accessing a single array element?
Because `data[0].Title` is undefined

Comment: You can add specific data to identify element before pushing it into an array.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      let newData = [
        {
          title: response.Title,
          text: response.Content,
        },
      ];
      data.push(newData);
      setData(newData);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

I'm assuming it was something like this you meant?
I couldn't get it to work as data[0].title is still undefined.

Comment: Instead of simple assigning, try like this. title: response.title ? response.title : ''

Comment: No that doesn't work either. 
Can i ask why push(response.data) was used over push(newData)
They don't seem to change anything if I swap them.

Comment: You pushed data before getting response. And I am not sure what you really want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235398/discussion-between-sirius-and-loafwad).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to divide the array into two halves and pass it to the `Element` component.

move the state to the parent component (`OmOss.js`) and fetch the array

find the middle index like `Math.floor(array.length/2)` and use this middle index to divide the array into two halves

two halves can be found using `array.slice(0, middleIndex)` and `array.slice(middleIndex)`

pass these arrays to the `Element` component as props

map the arrays and display the content